# How to specify one layer among many with getWMSFeatureInfo?

Tags: wms, layers, openlayers-2, getfeatureinfo

I am using OpenLayers `getWMSFeatureInfo` with multiple point layers.

When I click on a point on map, how to specify which layer that point belongs to?

Comment: Thanks for reply! I'm resolved problem!
I'm using GML in openlayers to parse document return from query (event.text)!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://gis.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Comment: Please post how you resolved the problem in answer. This way you can get reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand what you mean, but you can find a docs of WMSGetFeatureInfo object of OL [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/WMSGetFeatureInfo-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo.OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo). You might be interested mainly in drillDown and layers properties. That's how you can set what layers will be queried on click.

Answer (score 0):

you can get your layer information from your feature. if you alert your f info when click as shown in following code, you can get what you want.

```
f.layer.name //or anything
```

i hope it helps you...